# maintenance plan executing by agent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, maintenance, sharepoint

I have a built-in, regular maintenance plan scheduled to run weekly.

The databases are SharePoint databases and a snap manager (`netapp snap manager`) backs up these databases.

The rebuild maintenance plan is executed whenever the backup runs by the `SQL` server agent.

Why and how is this job being called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a SQL event being throw when the snap manager starts the backup?  If so there could be an alert setup on that event which is setup to start the job.  Check the SQL Agent alerts to see if it is configured to capture anything.

Comment: Yes, that is my guess but i am not exactly sure where to look for SQL event. The SQL alert is to send an email when the job runs/fails.

Comment: That's a job alert.  Under SQL Agent, look under alerts. Is there anything in there?

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Denny. You helped me to get to the root cause of this.

Answer (score 2):

When a maintenance plan is created, a SQL agent job is also created to run the maintenance plan. This way, you can run the job manually or schedule it. If you look inside the steps of the SQL agent job, you will see how the maintenance plan is being called.

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. But, the jobs are scheduled to run weekly. Why would the rebuild indexes kick in when the backup start to run? that is what I can't figure out.